# How to generalize container adaptors with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, stack, queue, conversion-operator

I've got the following class:

```
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class MySet
{
    public:
        const std::stack<T> data() const
        {
            std::stack<T> other_cont ( typename std::stack<T>::container_type ( cont.begin(), cont.end() ) );
            return other_cont;
        }

    private:
        std::set<T> cont;
};
```

And the following code:

```
MySet<std::string> a;
MySet<int> b;

const std::stack<std::string> s = a.data();
const std::queue<int> q = b.data();
```

I would like to use one templated member function to initialize any adaptor type.
So far it only works with either `stack` or `queue`, I can't figure out how to use templates to generalize it.

This is what I've tried:

```
template <template <typename> typename M>
const M<T> data() const
{
    M<T> other_cont ( typename M<T>::container_type ( cont.begin(), cont.end() ) );
    return other_cont;
}
```

Compiler says it can't deduce the template parameter `M`.

Comment: I don't think the compiler can ever deduce the parameter in your case. Try const `std::queue<int> q = b.data<std::queue>();` or even `std::queue<int> q = b.data<std::queue<int>>();`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this is part of some material from past years' exam and I can't touch the second block of code.

Comment: I just assumed I should solve this with templates since the code seems to be identical for both adaptors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your calling code:

```
a.data()
```

There is nothing here for `data()` to deduce its return type. You have to precise it explicitly, something like:

```
a.data<std::stack>()
```

But, from your comments, you can't edit the usage code. What you can do is using a template type conversion operator:

```
template <typename M>
operator M() const
{
    M other_cont ( typename M::container_type ( cont.begin(), cont.end() ) );
    return other_cont;
}
```

To keep the code unedited, your `data` method should return this object:

```
const MySet<T> data() const
{
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple approach is to use a conversion operator:

```
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class MySet
{
    public:
        template <typename O, typename = typename O::container_type>
        operator O() const
        {
            return O(typename O::container_type(cont.begin(), cont.end()));
        }

    private:
        std::set<T> cont;
};
```

Using this approach the notation is different, though: there is no `data()` member being used:

```
int main()
{
    MySet<std::string> s;
    std::stack<std::string> st = s;
    std::queue<std::string> qu = s;
}
```

If you want to use a `data()` member and get different types out of the result, you'll need to return a proxy which converts appropriately upon access:

```
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class MySet
{
    public:
        class Proxy {
            std::set<T> const* set;
        public:
            Proxy(std::set<T> const* s): set(s) {}
            template <typename O, typename = typename O::container_type>
            operator O() const
            {
                return O(typename O::container_type(set->begin(), set->end()));
            }
        };

        Proxy data() const { return Proxy{&this->cont}; }
    private:
        std::set<T> cont;
};

int main()
{
    MySet<std::string> s;
    std::stack<std::string> st = s.data();
    std::queue<std::string> qu = s.data();
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to wrapping it in a Proxy class instead of defining the conversion operator right in MySet? ( Like in @wasthishelpful-s answer )

Comment: Same question for `typename = typename O::container_type`, do I lose anything if I just use `template <typename O>`

Comment: @Jani: essentially the error messages are different. Using my SFINAE approach will say there is no appropriate conversion operator if the destination type doesn't have a nested `container_type`. Without it, there will be an error about the implementation being wrong. On SFINAE contexts my implementation won't claim that it is convertable. Whether you use a proxy or not depends on whether you want to force mention `data()` or not.